I fear he wants you to finish
In French, it's quite easy to say: "He wants you to finish":

Il veut que tu finis.

... but how to say: "I fear that he wants you to finish."?

Je crains qu'il ne veuille que tu finis.
Je crains qu'il ne veuille que tu finisses.

In other words:

The fact that your main verb changes into subjonctif, has no effect on your subclause.
The fact that your main verb changes into subjonctif, causes your subclause to change into subjonctif too.


Malheureusement, pas si facile : "Il veut que tu finis" ne se dit pas. C'est une erreur de locuteur non natif ou d'enfant / Sadly, it's not that easy, you can't say "Il veut que tu finis". It is really a non-native or children mistake.

"Je veux tu fu finis ton devoir.", that's a normal sentence, isn't it? (Ok, you might use "terminer" instead of "finir" but my question is just about the conjugation.)

no it's subjonctive too. Je veux que tu finisse ton devoir.

Well now I understand. If you use terminer or any 1st group verb (chanter), you can't tell if it's subjonctive or not on certain conjugations. But it is. Je veux que tu fasse etc.

@XouDo que tu finisses

Il veut que tu finisses, subjonctif. No other possibility.

@Dominique it's subjunctive no matter what. The double/nested que clause doesn't change the mood in the inner clause.

Vouloir being a verb of volonté1 is necessarily followed by the subjunctive (or the infinitive.)

Il veut que tu finisses.

Consequently, there is no change regardless of the main verb:

Je crains qu'il ne veuille que tu finisses.

With a different verb like voir, your first hypothesis is correct:

Je vois que tu finis.


Je crains qu'il ne voie que tu finis. (or: que tu as fini)

1 See About Subjunctive/Konjunctive

... and what if you replace "vouloir" by "voir" (I see that you finish)? I'm mostly interested in the phrase "Je crains qu'il ne voie que tu ...".

@Dominique Wait, after reading my reply, I'm not that convinced that the indicative is incorrect. Let me think about it.

@Dominique Answer corrected. The indicative would be used here.

Je vois que tu as fini un peu plus naturel? Et je crains qu'il ne voie que tu aies fini ou je crains qu'il ne voie que tu as fini.

@Frank 1. Oui, mais il n'a peut-être pas encore fini...  2. Je crains qu'il ne voie que tu as fini. puisque là, la personne a clairement fini, il n'y a pas de doute ou d'hypothèse.

@jlliagre oui oui - pas de problème. Je pense que le subjonctif devient de moins en moins courant, et qu'on a peut-être tendance à chercher des expressions qui permettent de l'éviter.

@Frank L'imparfait et le plus-que-parfait ont quasiment disparu, c'est sûr, mais le présent et le passé ne sont souvent guère remplaçables. Le présent du subjonctif gagne même du terrain après après que…
